# Subscribe method called multiple times in Angular on link click

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a navbar component code is

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menu">
   <a *ngSwitchCase="'link'" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="item.routerLink" (click)="Navigation(item.title)">    
   <span class="pr-2">{{item.title}}  </span></a>
</li>
```

whenever i click on any link i have to load content of rightside component. I have added `(click)="Navigation(item.title)"` method in the above link to track the changes in route

In navbar.ts file

```
  Navigation(data)
  {
     this.Service.Details.next(data);
     this.name(this.name);
  }

  name(data){
    this.selectedName=data;
    this.Service.Number.next(data);
  }
```

I have one dropdown also in navbar to select current user `Navigation` method is used to select the menu and `name` is used to track current user so that whenever selected user changes the new data is refreshed.

On my `rightside` component inside oninit method

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
 this.type = this.route.snapshot.data.router;
 this.Service.Number.subscribe(data => {
   if (this.type == 'url-1') {
     this.fetchData();
    }
    else if(this.type="url-2)
    {
     this.fetchData();
    }
     ..
 }); 
}
```

I have two issues

1. Subscribes method get called multiple times and api too.
2. I have used only `this.Service.Number` subscribe but i also want to check `this.Service.Details` in both the cases need to refetch the data but presently subscribing to only one.

Note: `this.Service.Details` is used to reload the current url suppose if i click on the same menu the it refetch the data

any solution to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Already tried [`.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-video-player/src/lib/components/video-player/video-player.component.ts#L351)?

Comment: @Pieterjan getting this error `Property 'take' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'`

Comment: Not `take`, but `.pipe`. As in `this.Service.Number.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((n) => {});`

Answer (score 1):

did you use .pipe(take(1)) ?
take operator will execute only 1 time.

Comment: Getting this error `Property 'take' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'`

Comment: import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

did you import it from rxjs operators ?